# How to make metrics of LM-fonts the same as of CM-fonts?

Tags: font-metrics

In the [article about LM-fonts](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb24-1/jackowski.pdf) it's written:

> Finally, they can be used with the CM metrics (e.g., via psfonts.map), so as to preserve typesetting of existing documents.

IMHO, font metrics are part of TeX's algorithms and they should be changed in tfm-files, aren't they?
How to change the metrics via psfonts.map, and are there any other ways to do that?

Comment: I think the document simply describes that one can
use CM tfms and LM glyphs, for example, like
`cmr10 LMRoman10-Regular "enclmrm ReEncodeFont" <lm-rm.enc <lmr10.pfb`,
`dvips -u+test.map dviname.dvi`,
where test.map is a map file which contains lines as above,
and dviname.dvi is created by CM tfms.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Make this an answer please. Take this test.tex: `a \'o \bye` where accent \'o will be ó `00F3 oacute` in LM-fonts. Is it possible to do similar trick via virtual fonts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article about LM-fonts simply describes that
one can use CM metrics and LM glyphs by making
a suitable map file. For example,

```
% test.map
cmr10 LMRoman10-Regular "enclmrm ReEncodeFont" <lm-rm.enc <lmr10.pfb
...
```

A dvips command line with the above map file may look like

```
dvips -u+test.map dviname.dvi
```

where dviname.dvi is created by using CM tfm files.
In the case of complicated glyphs, one may have to create
encoding files:

```
cmr10 LMRoman10-Regular "Myenclmrm ReEncodeFont" <Mylm-rm.enc <lmr10.pfb
```

Comment: Please use this test.tex: `a \'o \bye`  How do we transform it from CM-fonts to LM-fonts with the same metrics as CM-fonts? What will become with letter ó? Please put full description.

Comment: cmr10.tfm does not have metrics for > 127. Thus I think
`\'o` is typeset by the same method as in cmr10.
There may be workaround, but I don't have investigated
the issue.